# Is it possible to specify per-file lock types?

Tags: tfs, vcs-checkout

We have e.g. an excel sheet in the repository that is used for code generation. When any developer has checked out the excel sheet it should not be checked out by anyone else. This can be done by specifying the "Check Out lock type" via the check out dialog. But this has to be done manually by the developer. Is there a way to force this lock type on several files so that it is used automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify which file types are mergeable. You can change the setting in Team -> Team Project Collection Settings -> Source Control File Types.

Comment: I don't want to merge the excel sheet, I want to prevent them from being checked out multiple times.

Comment: @PVitt -If you set the file as not being mergeable, it will automatically lock the file on check-out.